# Biztalk message propery promotion

Tags: biztalk, biztalk2006r2

I have an orchestration which should be kicked off when a text file comes in from a receive location,
as far as I can see things look as they should but the orchestration isn't starting and I get this in the admin console:

> The published message could not be routed because no subscribers were found. This error occurs if the subscribing orchestration or send port has not been enlisted, or if some of the message properties necessary for subscription evaluation have not been promoted. Please use the BizTalk Administration console to troubleshoot this failure.

Does this mean I have to promote the message properties and if so do I do that in the orchestration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a text file, the inbound message will not by default have enough information in it to allow the BTS runtime to route your message. You need to pass the message into a flat file dissembler, which will convert your flat file message into an xml message.

The process of disassembly to xml will *promote* certain things into the *context* of the message, one of which will be the *message type*.

By default this is what your orchestration subscription will be based on if you have set things up in the most usual fashion.

Your problem is likely due to one of the following:

1. You don't have a flat file disassembler as a stage in your inbound pipeline, or it is set up incorrectly.
2. Your orchestration subscription is for a message type which does not match the type of message being dissembled.

To further troubleshoot, after starting your orchestration run a query for subscriptions from the BizTalk Admin Console. You should be able to see a row (or two) for your orchestration, with type = "Activation".

You should be able to see the criteria against which the BTS engine will have to successfully evaluate so that inbound messages reach your orchestration.

Also you can enable tracking on inbound messages and inspect the body of the message which comes in before and after disassembly.

Hope this helps